# remove all email,external links,contact number and few words Regex

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have an text area in which i want to remove all the emails,extarnal links ,contact numbers and few fixed words.also I want to permit a external link.I have tried for this but has not got success will you help me please.Here is my html

```js
var str=$('#textarea_before').html();
var toagaincheck = str.replace(/(at\)|@|www|http|https).*?(\.|dot\))(com|in|org|uk|ac|!)/g, '');
var last_second_check = toagaincheck.replace(/(\.|dot\))(com|ac|in|org|uk)/g, '');
var last_check = last_second_check.replace(/\d{5,}/g, '');
var last_before = last_check.replace(/google|yahoo|mozilla/g, '');
var result=last_before.replace(/(\(d{5,}|((\d|\s){10,}))/g, '');
$('#textarea_after').html(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea rows='10' cols='50' id='textarea_before'>
  Hi Ravi Prakash Awasthi,
  I am ravi from algocrats. persuing my M.Tech from http://www.iitd.ac.in or http://iitd.ac.in I wanna contact You through  email or contact number. Can you send me your email or contact me in my email (i.e. ravi.awasthi93@gmail.com). My contact no is 1234587585.I am trying to write my contact like 1 2 3 4 5 8 7 5 8 5.
  I want to permit a link that is http://www.rgpv.ac.in but it also being replaced.
</textarea>
<textarea rows='10' cols='50' id='textarea_after'></textarea>
```

help me to make regex in two max lines and how to permit to include a external link. thanks......

Comment: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jqqza85n/)

Comment: To start with, let's combine all your `replace` statements.[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jqqza85n/1/). How will you permit links, yet remove them as you want to do?

Comment: I dont have idea but if it remove that link and replace with a variable and at last put it again

Comment: No, my question is , do you want external links or not?

Comment: yes only one link and it is pre-fixed

Comment: You only want to permit the links with `rgpv`?

Comment: Are you trying to limit site's internal messaging so somebody like freelancer wouldn't be able to contact customer outside through regular email? What stops them from just scrambling their address?

Answer (score 0):

try this  [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jqqza85n/5/)

```
var str=$('#textarea_before').html();
var toagaincheck = str.replace(/\b(http:(?!\/*www\.holidayporch\.com)|www\.\.holidayporch\.com).*?\s|\b[^\s]+@[a-z]+\.[a-z]+\b|\b(\d\s*){10}\b|\b(google|yahoo|mozilla)\b/gi, '');
var result=toagaincheck;
$('#textarea_after').html(result);
```

Where allow = http://www.holidayporch.com

Just add the fixed word which you want to remove and also phone number length is assumed as 10 if other than this then also mention it too. example if phone length is 7 then (\d\s*){7}

Comment: suppose I want to permit only for `http://www.holidayporch.com`,how to permit this external link in the text area

Comment: \b(http:(?!\/*www\.holidayporch\.com)|www\.\.holidayporch\.com).*?\s|\b[^\s]+@[a-z]+\.[a-z]+\b|\b(\d\s*){10}\b|\b(google|yahoo|mozilla)\b